# How to filter the imported data in only the first column and also the columns that contain the word "Total" as the menu title

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Imported columns with title `Total` can change their position, only the first column always remains in the same place:

[image]

The formula used:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2021/02/06/england/premier-league/aston-villa-football-club/arsenal-fc/3344352/"&"head2head/",
"//div[@class='block_h2hsection_team real-content clearfix ']//table[@class='table compare section-dropdowns']//option[@selected='selected'] | 
//div[@class='block  clearfix block_h2h_general_statistics-wrapper body-table header-wrapper']//tr")
```

1 - I need to use only one function `IMPORTXML` because the spreadsheet is already at the limit so as not to collapse due to several imports.

2 - The `Home` and `Away` columns are of no use to me, so I would like to exclude them to take up less space.

3 - I tried to use the `QUERY` function to try to select, but I can only do this if the words `Total` were on the first row of the imported data and also if the first column was always the same word, but that doesn't happen either, the `Premier League - 2020/2021` value happens in that specific game, but in other games they are other names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2021/02/06/england/premier-league/aston-villa-football-club/arsenal-fc/3344352/"&"head2head/",
 "//div[@class='block_h2hsection_team real-content clearfix ']//table[@class='table compare section-dropdowns']//option[@selected='selected'] | 
  //div[@class='block  clearfix block_h2h_general_statistics-wrapper body-table header-wrapper']//tr")), 
 "where not Col4 matches 'Away|Home'"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi  @player0 ! Could you please provide some information on how you solved the problem such as references to the functions you used and how your implementation solves the question? Thanks !

Comment: @MateoRandwolf https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Comment: In this answer the user has used two [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) functions. The purpose of them is to 1. to be able to select with ```QUERY``` the righ columns and 2. to leave the resulting range on its original format.